# Direct product of locally supersoluble groups

Tags: group-theory

I'd like to know if the direct product of two locally supersoluble groups is locally supersoluble. Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: Have you thought about it at all?

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about it for all the day but I've not been able to prove whether it's true or false. Can you just give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $M = \langle (x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_t, y_t) \rangle$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $G \times H$. Then $M$ is contained in

$$\langle x_1, \ldots, x_t \rangle \times \langle y_1, \ldots, y_t\rangle$$

Comment: I thought that this was the way to prove. I thought that if $A=<x_1,\dots ,x_t>$ and $B=<y_1,\dots ,y_t>$, since they are two finitely generated subgroups of $G$ and $H$, respectively, $A$ e $B$ are supersoluble. I know that the direct product of two supersoluble groups is supersoluble. Can I be sure that the subgroup generated by $A$ e $B$ is the direct product of them? I thought it wasn't, because I don't know if they are normal in $G\times H$.

Comment: @Rob: In the direct product $G \times H$, you have $gh = hg$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$. So if $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $ab = ba$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. With this you can show that $A$ is normal in $A \times B$ and $B$ is normal in $A \times B$, hence the subgroup $A \times B$ is the direct product of $A$ and $B$. Is this what you meant?